# how to create a google form response with app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

As a way of initializing a form record, I want to fill and submit a google form with apps script. The key bit of documentation for form.createResponse() is this

> Creates a new response to the form. To answer a question item, create
>   an ItemResponse from the item, then attach it to this form response by
>   calling FormResponse.withItemResponse(response). To save the assembled
>   response, call FormResponse.submit().

do I need to new FormResponse() or how do I make this happen?

Answer (score 9):

create new form

```
    var test_form = FormApp.create('test1');
    test_form.addTextItem();
```

get the first question as a text item

```
    var questions = test_form.getItems();
    var qt = questions[0].asTextItem();
```

set the response

```
    var qr = qt.createResponse('cats');
```

create and submit a response object

```
    var FormResponse = test_form.createResponse();
    FormResponse.withItemResponse( qr );
    FormResponse.submit();
```

Comment: There are two different `createResponse()` methods.  Exact same name, but used on two different things.  One is used on an item, with a parameter of what the answer will be: [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item#createresponseresponse)  The other has no parameter and is used on the Form to create the response as a whole.  [new response to the form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createresponse)

Comment: this also can be used to produce prefilled urls.